# Aligning md-select dropdown menu to the bottom of the trigger element

Tags: vue.js, material-design, vue-material

I'm using vue-material Is there a way to customize the menu to show up aligned to the bottom of the md-select-value input field?

I tried using :md-direction="bottom-start", but it doesn't seem to work.

This is what I get:

[image]

But I want it to be like this:

[image]

```
    <md-field>
      <label for="country">Country</label>
      <md-select v-model="countryname" name="countryname" id="country" :md-direction="bottom-start">
        <md-option value="australia">Australia</md-option>
        <md-option value="brazil">Brazil</md-option>
        <md-option value="japan">Japan</md-option>
        <md-option value="united-states">United States</md-option>
      </md-select>
    </md-field>
```